# How to concat two metrics value in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I need to display the two metrics values in single stats panel like the below output

Example

Input :

`mysql_global_status_threads_connected{service_name="$service_name"}/mysql_global_variables_max_connections{service_name="$service_name"}`

the value of

`mysql_global_status_threads_connected  = 21`

`mysql_global_variables_max_connections = 100`

Output

with the backslash

`21/100`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you cannot implement this with promql. But by using HTTP API you can have this as below:

```
echo $(curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=mysql_global_status_threads_connected' | jq -r '.data.result[].value[1]')/$(curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=mysql_global_variables_max_connections' | jq -r '.data.result[].value[1]')
```